# Can I remove a disc from Windows Storage Spaces without deleting the files?

Tags: storage

As the title says, I want to remove a disc from a Windows Storage Space (there are no other discs in the space), without removing the contents?

Is this possible, and if not how would I workaround the problem of not wanting to delete the files?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a way to convert Storage Spaces back to Basic Disk
without losing contents.

The procedure as I see it:

- Backup your data
- Destroy the pool - if the user-interface does not have that option,
  use PowerShell [Remove-StoragePool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/remove-storagepool?view=win10-ps)
- Format the disk
- Restore the data.